# Elasticsearch english language analyzer with nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

First time trying to implement elastic search using aws hosted service with nodejs. Referred to the official docs and came up with this:

```
//1. create index
client.indices.create({ index: 'products' });

//2. mapping
client.indices.putMapping({
        index: 'products',
        type: 'products',
        body: {
            properties: {
                'product_name': {
                    'type': 'string',
                    "analyzer": "english"
                },
                'product_description': {
                    'type': 'string',
                    "analyzer": "english"
                }
            }
        }
    });

//3. import documents..
product_name: Testing


//4. search 
client.search({
        index: 'products',
        type: 'products',
        q: keywords,
        analyzer: 'english',
        size: 10
    });
```

Now, if I search for 'Testing' or 'Token Testing', this returns 1 result. But if I test passing 'Test' or 'Tist' as a keyword, seems the analyzer isn't picking up and I get no results.

**Updated:** Added analyzer: 'english' according to @Val answer, but still no results for 'Test' or 'Tist'.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when using the `q` parameter, a `query_string` query is made and the default analyzer of your input string is the `standard` analyzer.

You have two choices here:

A. Include the field name in your query string:

```
client.search({
    index: 'products',
    type: 'products',
    q: 'product_name:' + keywords,    <--- modify this
    size: 10
});
```

B. Specify `english` as the query-time analyzer to produce the same tokens as has been previously indexed:

```
client.search({
    index: 'products',
    type: 'products',
    q: keywords,
    analyzer: 'english',              <--- or add this
    size: 10
});
```

Comment: gave a try to both ways u suggested. It's still the same - no result :(

Comment: Please update your question with what you get when calling `curl -XGET localhost:9200/products`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this part.

Comment: Run the above command on your ES cluster and share the response you get form ES.

Comment: this is what i get: {"products":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"products":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"long"},"product_description":{"type":"text","analyzer":"english"},"product_name":{"type":"text","analyzer":"english"}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1501055439955","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"ID_HERE","version":{"created":"5030299"},"provided_name":"products"}}}}

Comment: Also note that `Tist` will never return anything

Comment: ah ok. thought it's part of the english analyzer work. anyways, would be more than happy if i got 'test' to return me 'tester' and 'testing'

Comment: Which version of ES do you have?

Comment: it's 5.3, aws hosted.